# jQuery Draggable to Sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

Good day!

I right now have a function the drags an element from a list to a sortable list.

But what I want to achieve is to insert my own created html elements  when i drag it to the sortable list and not to insert the elements selected from the draggable list.

Appreciate you help in advance!

Thanks,
steamboy

Comment: Post code, always!  Your markup and jQuery and what you **want** to happen as a result make this immensely easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at "receive" callback: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive and modify ui.item :)